# Сумма элементов при дубликате ключа с помощью Stream

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Помогите пожалуйста. Мне из стрима необходимо получить Map, в котором в качестве ключа будет находиться остаток от деления, а в качестве value  будет сумма чисел для которых этот остаток получился. Делитель дан заранее.
вот мой код:

```
   int a = 2; делитель
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3 ,4, 5);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> list.get(x) % a,Collectors.summingInt(list::get)));
   System.out.println(map);
```

но у меня появляется ошибка java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5.

Объясните почему она появляется и что мне надо подкорректировать. ТАкже подскажите каким образом я бы мог использовать метод getOrDefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) передается функция. Её описание говорит, что она преобразует входящие элементы в ключи. Поскольку это не индексы, а сами элементы, попытка получить элемент по индексу `5` заканчивается неудачей. Был бы у вас `Arrays.asList(20);`, то получили бы ошибку `Index 20 out of bounds for length 5`. Думаю логика понятная.

Вторая функция [Collectors.summingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) принимает по описанию функцию преобразования элемента в int. Поскольку у вас опять же это не индекс, то вам просто надо преобразовать элемент Integer к int.

Советую вам выполнить и понять следующий код:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     int a = 2;
     List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 3, 12, 5);
     Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
     map = list.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> { 
                 System.out.println("получен элемент для преобразования в ключ: " + x +"; ключ " + x % a + ";");
                 return x % a; 
             }, Collectors.summingInt(x -> {
                 System.out.println("получен элемент для последующего сложения: " + x);
                 return x.intValue(); 
             })));
     System.out.println(map);
}
```

Итог:

```
map = list.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x % a, Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue)));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснения. Я понял , что в коллектор передавать list.get(x) ошибочно, так как в коллекторе итак уже передаются значения из стрима, развернутого из list